# Getting error when try to insert GetDate() into database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database

I am trying to insert today's date and try increment the date recursively. but I am getting conversion error message.

```
private void InsertTimesheetWeek(string timeSheetID)
{
    int row = GViewTimeSheet.Rows.Count;//get the row count
    int counter = 0;

    string[] txtDate = new string[row];// date column

    foreach (GridViewRow gRow in GViewTimeSheet.Rows)
    {

        txtDate[counter] = "GetDATE()+"+counter;

        counter++;
    }

    //Intializing sql statement
    string fields = "(TimeSheetID, Date)";
    string parm = "(@TimeSheetID, @Date)";
    string sqlStatement = "insert into TimeSheetWeeks" + fields + "Values" + parm;

    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
    comm.CommandText = sqlStatement;//assing sql statement as command
    SqlConnection connection = DataAccess.getConnection();
    comm.Connection = connection;

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        {
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeSheetID", timeSheetID);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", txtDate[i]);

            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            comm.Parameters.Clear();
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Utilities.LogError(ex);
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)// if the connection opened then 
        {
            connection.Close();//just close the connection in any way
        }
    }
}
```

Why it causes an error?

Comment: What is the error message you getting?? Also try run with breakpoint and check what is the value you passing **"@Date", txtDate[i]**, probably the value inside **txtDate[i]** cause the error

Comment: Error message: "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.". I try debugging, Every thing seems good(the values "GetDATE()+0","GetDATE()+1", "GetDATE()+2"....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is caused by passing "GetDATE()+1", "GetDATE()+2", etc. as a parameter and SQL can't convert this to a date.

Do the date calculations in code before sending to SQL:

```
txtDate[counter] = DateTime.Now.AddDays(counter);
```

The approach you've taken would work if you were building the SQL statement as a literal for each row.
ex:*

```
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
{
    string fields = "(TimeSheetID, Date)";
    string parm = String.Format"({0}, GetDATE() + {1})", timeSheetID, i);
    string sqlStatement = "insert into TimeSheetWeeks" + fields + "Values" + parm;

    // ....
```

***N.B. Don't use the above code - I've provided it as an example only.  Always use SQL parameters if possible.  Parameters are type-safe and mitigate the risk of SQL injection. [How To: Protect From SQL Injection in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx)**

Answer (score 2):

I would do two things:

1) move the creation of the parameter out of the loop - you only need to create them once

2) don't use the `AddWithValue` method, since that method has to **guess** the datatype - and it might get it wrong at times

So use this:

```
// Intializing sql statement
string fields = "(TimeSheetID, Date)";
string parm = "(@TimeSheetID, @Date)";
string sqlStatement = "insert into TimeSheetWeeks" + fields + "Values" + parm;

using(SqlConnection connection = DataAccess.getConnection())
using(SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, connection))
{
   comm.Parameters.Add("@TimeSheetID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50); // just guessing
   comm.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime);

   try
   {
      connection.Open();

      for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
      {
          comm.Parameters["@TimeSheetID"] = timeSheetID;
          comm.Parameters["@Date"] = txtDate[i];

          comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }

      connection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Utilities.LogError(ex);
        throw;
    }
}
```

As others have already pointed out, your syntax for

```
txtDate[counter] = "GetDATE()+"+counter;
```

also is a bit odd - what are you trying to do here?? What are you trying to add - `counter` days? Months? Years? Seconds?`Not clear at all ....

Maybe you can "move" that logic to the point where you're setting the date's value:

```
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
{
   comm.Parameters["@TimeSheetID"] = timeSheetID;
   comm.Parameters["@Date"] = DateTime.Today.AddDays(i);  // is that what you need?

   comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: I assume the intent is to add days as that is the behavior of "date + #" in SQL

Comment: Yes I am trying to increment the days. Ur last method helped me solve the prob. Thanx

Answer (score 2):

Try changing this:

```
txtDate[counter] = "GetDATE()+"+counter;
```

To this:

```
txtDate[counter] = DateTime.Now.AddDays(counter);
```